# Co-worker sorted 1 column of massive excel worksheet. How to...never again

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook that contained a worksheet with like 20 columns and a zillion rows.  It had conditional formatting rules, macros, connected to a database. Very important stuff.
Here's the problem, one of my co-workers (my co-workers have access to the sheet), decided he would sort JUST ONE COLUMN of the sheet, without expanding the sort selction to the surrounding rows.  So, now I am rebuilding from scratch. It's going to take weeks.

How do I prevent users from sorting without keeping the rows intact?

Comment: Put a password on it and make it read only.

Comment: Use [Protect Sheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-HP010078580.aspx#BMprotectelements) it has an option to prevent sorting and more, you must unlock cells that you want users to edit.

Comment: try disabling the button via vba. http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/554763-vba-in-excel-know-a-way-to-disable-sort-without-protectsheet.html

Comment: I want it to be sortable, just not single columns. In other words, they need to sort and filter, but I need to insure the rows stay intact

Comment: Once sorting is disabled (as commented above), create a VB button to do the sorting. 

Alternatively could also add a formula at the top of the page that does some integrity checks (such as checking the values of Column A & C in the third row and making sure they correspond). Then if someone sorts just one column (or breaks something else), the formula will detect this and with conditional formatting can show a warning in BIG red letters asking them not to press save.

And also add a daily backup script to the server :)